# EF return parent entity only

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm having an issue when trying to serialise an entity. An error is being through saying that the query may result in a circular query. Ideally I just want to pull out the entity with no relationships attached. I've seen some examples where you can set the relation accessor to Internal but this causes other issues. Is there a way to do this in straight LINQ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please add some code showing how you are doing it now, so we can suggest modifications to your code. Also please be more clear as to what you want. Do you have an error or are you getting the entity with all relationships and you want to get only the entity without the related entities?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. An example of the query to return the entities is:
context.Item.Single(x => x.ID == id);
This returns the Parent, but when serialising the Entity the error is thrown. The Item table has a relationship with another table that hold combinations the combinations contain 3 fields. A unique ID, ItemID1, ItemID2. This table is used to create Parent-Child relationship between items. So in theory yes a circular reference is possible, though not likely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a single entity using FirstOrDefault()

The reason that you are getting the circular error is probably due to your data model where a row points to the parent which could be the same row.